# How to tell, in code, if form failed validation (client side)

Tags: jquery, validation

I am building an mvc app with jquery.validate, jquery.validate.unobtrusive etc.

I have a function I want to execute onclick of the submit button if the form is invalid, so I have been looking for a variable or flag or something that gets set on the client side when the validation fails, so I can fire my function based on that, but I have not been able to find anything that will work.  Anyone know of a global "Failed-Validation" variable in one of the jquery scripts? Or is there a function in the jquery validate stuff that would have that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do to hook into the client side validation. When a failure occurs, the user is prevented from posting the page, but I needed to log this on the server. You could easily replace the logJsError method with code of your choosing.

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('form').bind('invalid-form.validate',
            function (form, validator) {
                var message = $.map(validator.errorList, function (error) {
                    return error.message;
                }).join("\r\n");
                if (message) {
                    logJsError(message);
                }

            }
        );
    });
    function logJsError(message) {
        $.get('@page.Url.Action("Index", "Postback")?lastController=@page.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]&lastAction=@page.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + '&ts=' + (new Date().getTime()));
    }
```